# status ErrImageNeverPull unable to set up kubernetes dashboard on Mac

Tags: kubernetes

I am using DOCKER desktop to setup kubernetes. I have used below command to install kubernetes dashboard on mac

```
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/aio/test-resources/kubernetes-dashboard-local.yaml
```

when i use  `kubectl get pod --namespace=kube-system`

```
NAME                                              READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-6dcc67dcbc-2qdls                          1/1     Running             0          4h50m
coredns-6dcc67dcbc-nqm76                          1/1     Running             0          4h50m
etcd-docker-desktop                               1/1     Running             0          4h49m
kube-apiserver-docker-desktop                     1/1     Running             0          4h50m
kube-controller-manager-docker-desktop            1/1     Running             0          4h49m
kube-proxy-pq9pv                                  1/1     Running             0          4h50m
kube-scheduler-docker-desktop                     1/1     Running             0          4h49m
kubernetes-dashboard-local-599bb4877f-6nnkz       0/1     ErrImageNeverPull   0          138m
kubernetes-metrics-scraper-head-787ff8f87-rrq67   1/1     Running             0          138m
```

i wanted to know what is that "ErrImageNeverPull" of that POD. it is not even allowing me to describe/delete by that name.

```
kubectl describe pod kubernetes-dashboard-local-599bb4877f-6nnkz
```

Error from server (NotFound): pods "kubernetes-dashboard-local-599bb4877f-6nnkz" not found

How to fix or get rid of that so that i can successfully proceed further.

Answer (score 2):

[That YAML file](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/aio/test-resources/kubernetes-dashboard-local.yaml#L148-L149) specifies:

```
image: kubernetes/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64:head
imagePullPolicy: Never
```

So `ErrImageNeverPull` means that (a) that exact image name doesn't exist on the node where the pod is scheduled, and (b) `imagePullPolicy: Never` tells it to not try to fetch it.

Since the pod is not in the `default` namespace, you need to provide the `kubectl --namespace kube-system` option option to every command that tries to interact with it (not just `get pod` but also `describe pod`, `delete deployment`, *etc.*).

It looks like you've pulled a deployment spec from inside the dashboard's test tree which is intended to be used by a developer actively working on the dashboard code.  The [installation instructions](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard#getting-started) have a different YAML file to use.  (This link to the GitHub repo is probably more stable than the link to the version-specific YAML file that's there.)

Comment: first of all thanks for correcting namespace knowledge. i have been following this link "https://medium.com/@thms.hmm/docker-for-mac-with-kubernetes-enable-k8s-dashboard-62fe036b7480" to setup dashboard however after doing all that when i tried accesing http://localhost:8443/ i am ony seeing this message "Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server." on browser instead of whole dashboard UI

Comment: In the tutorial you mentioned there is nothing that could suggest using link you provided in your question. I see that the link provided in the article gives `404: Not Found`, so probably this was the reason you started looking for different one, but as @David suggested you shouldn't use the one you provided. Follow the instructions available on https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard#getting-started I've just tested them and everything works perfectly.